# Is it possible to pass a for loop in a function?

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, anova

I know it sounds ridiculous but I have to pass a for loop into a function. I have a dataframe with 75+ columns and most of them are categorical variables. One of the variable is called `SalePrice` and i wish to find the correlation between the categorical variables and `SalePrice`.

This is my code, but i think it is ridiculous to go through all 75 columns manually. Is there a easy way?

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, delimiter=',')
qualityTest = df[["OverallQual","SalePrice"]]
qualities = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
stats.f_oneway(qualityTest['SalePrice'][qualityTest['OverallQual'] == 1],
              qualityTest['SalePrice'][qualityTest['OverallQual'] == 2],
              qualityTest['SalePrice'][qualityTest['OverallQual'] == 3],
              qualityTest['SalePrice'][qualityTest['OverallQual'] == 4],
              qualityTest['SalePrice'][qualityTest['OverallQual'] == 5],
              qualityTest['SalePrice'][qualityTest['OverallQual'] == 6],
              qualityTest['SalePrice'][qualityTest['OverallQual'] == 7],
              qualityTest['SalePrice'][qualityTest['OverallQual'] == 8],
              qualityTest['SalePrice'][qualityTest['OverallQual'] == 9],
              qualityTest['SalePrice'][qualityTest['OverallQual'] == 10])
```

I've tried doing this but it doesnt work

```
stats.f_oneway(
    for i in qualities:
        qualityTest['SalePrice'][qualityTest['OverallQual'] == i]
)
```

Comment: you can use lambda

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension - essentially, create a list using a `for` loop, and pass that in:

```
stats.f_oneway([qualityTest['salePrice'][qualityTest['OverallQual'] == i] for i in qualities])
```

Or if you want it passed as *`i` separate arguments* instead of as *one list with `i` elements*, you can add an `*` right in front of the outermost set of square brackets (which will unpack the list you just made into function arguments).

Comment: Hi, I've tried both ways and it returned me with an error.
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. (For list)
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'generator' (After removing the outer most brackets)

Comment: Removing the outermost square brackets will pass a generator. If you want it the arguments to separate, you must use the `*` unpacking operator. Something like: `stats.f_oneway(*(qualityTest['salePrice'][qualityTest['OverallQual'] == i] for i in qualities))`

Comment: @Tomothy32 Thanks for that, I've updated my answer. Incidentally, why *doesn't* a generator work here, when it works for things like `print()` and the other stdlib functions that take an arbitrary number of arguments?

Comment: Could you give an example? Trying `print(i for i in range(5))` yields `<generator object <genexpr> at *memory address*>`. Maybe you meant unpacking an generator, like `print(*(i for i in range(5)))`.

Answer (score 3):

Using `groupby` here

```
qualityTest.groupby('OverallQual').OverallQual.apply(stats.f_oneway)
```